# Pine Script - Delta Volume with lower timeframe

Tags: function, volume, pine-script, indicator

I have the code for Delta Volume indicator for Tradingview. It gathers volume data on a lower timeframe (5 min) for a higher timeframe security chart. This seems to work okay apart from the last bar of the security. Here the 5min intervals with volume data get completely out of whack and show nonsense.
Any idea? Is this a problem within Pine Script?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 
https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=4

study(title="Volume Delta", shorttitle="Volume Delta", precision=2)
size = input(title="Fragment Size (minutes)", type=input.integer, defval=5, maxval=1440, minval=1)
// Comment: make sure you have set a large (default) fragment size before switching to a monthly 
chart
var string res = tostring(size)

periodMultiplier = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, timeframe.multiplier)
periodIsIntraday = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, timeframe.isintraday)
periodIsDaily = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, timeframe.isdaily)
periodIsWeekly = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, timeframe.isweekly)

int conversion = periodIsIntraday ? 1 : periodIsDaily ? 24 * 60 : periodIsWeekly ? 24 * 60 * 7 : 0
int count = barstate.islast ? floor((timenow - time)/(1000 * 60 * size)) + 1 : conversion * 
periodMultiplier / size

// variable to add or substract volume when computing delta volume
float tickVol = close > open ? volume : close < open ? -volume : 0.0

// function to compute delta volume, max and min delta volume and total delta volume
Vol() =>
    float deltaVol = 0.0
    float totalDeltaVol = 0.0
    float maxDeltaVol = 0.0
    float minDeltaVol = 0.0
    int temp = 0
    temp := count
    for i = 0 to temp - 1
        deltaVol := deltaVol + nz(tickVol[i])
        totalDeltaVol := totalDeltaVol + nz(abs(tickVol[i]))
        if deltaVol > maxDeltaVol
            maxDeltaVol := deltaVol
        if deltaVol < minDeltaVol
            minDeltaVol := deltaVol
    [deltaVol, maxDeltaVol, minDeltaVol, totalDeltaVol]

// calling security with lower timeframe resolution to compute up and down volume more accurately
[deltaVolume, maxDeltaVolume, minDeltaVolume, totalDeltaVolume] = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, 
Vol(), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)

// plotting delta volume bars
hline(0)
plot(deltaVolume, title="Delta Volume", style=plot.style_line, color=color.yellow, transp=65, 
offset=0)
//plot(totalDeltaVolume, title="Total Delta Volume", style=plot.style_line, color=color.blue, 
transp=65, offset=0)
//plot(maxDeltaVolume, title="Max Delta Volume", style=plot.style_line, color=color.green, transp=65, 
offset=0)
//plot(minDeltaVolume, title="Min Delta Volume", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red, transp=65, 
offset=0)
//plot(tickVol, title="Tick Volume", style=plot.style_line, color=color.fuchsia, transp=65, offset=0)

// computing cumulative delta volume
var float cumDeltaVolume = 0.0
cumDeltaVolume := cumDeltaVolume == 0.0 ? deltaVolume : nz(cumDeltaVolume[1]) + deltaVolume
//plot(cumDeltaVolume, title="Cumulative Delta Volume", style=plot.style_line, color=color.orange, 
transp=0, offset=0, linewidth=2)

// computing ohlc values to plot cumulative delta candles
var float o = 0.0
var float c = 0.0
o := cumDeltaVolume == deltaVolume ? 0.0 : c[1]
c := o + deltaVolume
float h = c + maxDeltaVolume - deltaVolume
float l = o + minDeltaVolume

// plotting cumulative delta volume candles
plotcandle(o <= c ? o : na, h, l, c, title="Cumulative Delta Green Candle", color = color.teal, 
wickcolor=color.teal, bordercolor=color.teal)
plotcandle(o >= c ? o : na, h, l, c, title="Cumulative Delta Red Candle", color = color.red, 
wickcolor=color.red, bordercolor=color.red)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's expected behavior. Intrabar segments are not aligned in the realtime bar. See the limits of using `security()` at intrabar TFs [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#is-it-possible-to-use-security-on-lower-intervals-than-the-charts-current-interval). It's not officially supported by TV.

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.